# Why I'm getting this error ORA-00001: unique constraint (HR.DEPT_ID_PK) violated?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Here I'm inserting row to Built-in departments table in oracle 11g but when I execute the query I'm getting this error

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (HR.DEPT_ID_PK) violated.

Help is appreciate an advanced.

```
enter code here
{
    INSERT INTO HR.departments(department_id,  
    department_name, manager_id, location_id) 
    VALUES (70, 'Public Relations', 100, 1700);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indicating that 70 is already available in this table as departmetn_id. Please check. Then change the department_id you are trying to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your intention is to *update* an existing row rather than *inserting* a new row:

```
UPDATE HR.departments
    SET (department_name, manager_id, location_id) = ('Public Relations', 100, 1700)
    WHERE department_id = 70;
```